# Word (Along with space) search in T Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column `Transactions` in a SQL Server table `A`.

I have around 1000 rows in that table, and in each row I have strings which has combination of

```
 "@transaction --space of 3 characters---1" or "@transaction --space of 3 characters---0" these strings may be even repeated n number of times within the single row.
```

Result - I want to check all the

```
"@transaction --space of 3 characters---1"  ones how many times repeated.
"@transaction --space of 3 characters---0"  zeros how many times repeated.
```

I tried with queries such as

```
Select * from A where transaction like '%@transaction --space of 3 characters---1%
Select * from A where transaction like '%@transaction --space of 3 characters---0%
```

But these can't give me the desired result because there may be more number of above strings in single column.

Can anyone suggest how to count all these two strings with ending 1 and 0 separately ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the percentage symbol on both start and end, and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT count (*) as [Count], 'Strings with 1' as [Comment]
FROM A 
WHERE transaction like cast (@transaction as varchar(50)) +'???1%'

UNION ALL

SELECT count (*) as [Count], 'Strings with 0'
FROM A 
WHERE transaction like cast (@transaction as varchar(50)) +'???0%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response i appreciate it . But the only problem is that within the single row this expression may be repeated many number of times. so this search should work within the row as well as across the rows to look for the expression.

Comment: List all columns with OR and use same clause. You can concatenate wall char columns with + (plus) sign and apply use in in where clause like `where col1+col2+col3 like ...`. If necessary, cast char to varchar(max) or nvarchar (max).

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable inputs Stoleg!! I highly appreciate you!